# How assign id to objects in Leaflet.Draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet.draw

How can I assign a unique number (id)  to all objects in Leaflet.Draw. And how can edit the elements individually? When i'm click on Edit button, all elements are editable. I want edit only which i clicked. P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: have you found any solution for this?